# Integral of zero length

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let $f(x)$ be real Riemann(or Lebesgue) integrable (possibly improper) function.

My question is whether the following always holds:

$$\lim_{|I|\to 0}\int_{I}|f(x)|dx=0$$

where $I$ is a finite interval on the real line and $|I|$ is the length of interval.

When $f(x)$ is bounded, it is obvious since the interval shrinks. I am interested in the case when $f(x)$ has integrable poles, especially when it has infinitely many poles (accumulation point of poles).

Comment: Given $\epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that $\int_E |f|<\epsilon$ whenever $\mu (E) <\delta$. This standard. Any book on Measure Theory has a proof.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Oh, thank you. I'll look up.

Comment: $\int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon} \text{f.p.} \frac1{x^2}dx$ is always infinite (here $\text {f.p.}$ means the function is defined to be zero at the pole). Is it what you was asking for?

Comment: @Anixx No, I am asking about integrals like $\int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon}\frac{1}{\sqrt |x|}dx$ which is $0$ still having a pole at the origin.

Comment: @Anixx Lebesgue/Riemann integrable specifically means the integral is finite, so that is not a valid example.